# Log user access in a windows domain

Tags: login, active-directory, windows-event-log

I need to log all users access to computer in a mysql database. I need datetime, user and workstation, how to do it? How to set up an event on domain controllers?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I would like to use the system log, but seems a bit difficult to filter only the user-access and redirect it to a mysql.

Comment: Check out splunk, it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Read the logon events in the domain controllers and log the details to your DB.